# java - String.replaceAll to replace all characters not in pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a Java regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,126}$
```

It means:

- Begin with an alphabetic character or underscore character.
- Subsequent characters may include letters, digits or underscores.
- Be between 1 and 127 characters in length.

Now, I want to replace a string having characters not in that regex with a underscore.

Example:

```
final String label = "23_fgh99@#";
System.out.println(label.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z_][^a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,126}$", "_"));
```

But the result is still `23_fgh99@#`.

How can I "convert" it to `_3_fgh99__`?

Comment: Because "23_fgh99@#" begins with `2`, not `[a-zA-Z_]`, no matches.

Comment: Try `label.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z_]|(?<!^)[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "_")`. It outputs `_3_fgh99__`, though.

Comment: Oops, it seems I have an answer after an edit :).

Answer (score 4):

Use [this code](https://ideone.com/M6zQLy):

```
final String label = "23_fgh99@#";
System.out.println(label.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z_]|(?<!^)[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "_"));
```

It outputs `_3_fgh99__`.

To remove what is "not in the original pattern", you need to negate the first character class and only check a character at the beginning (`^[^a-zA-Z_]`), and then check other characters not at the beginning with the negated second character class (`(?<!^)[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Then, we just use an alternation symbol `|` to apply both patterns in 1 replacement operation.

Comment: Please try to explain your answer for future users.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Sure, I explain my answers in most cases, and this case seems quite peculiar.

Comment: @java_guy: Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.